# How do you pass a parameter to a function when that function is assigned using observe?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have about 12 div elements in a class called "item"

i have used for-loop to attach a onClick javascript function to each one of them:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $$(".item").length; i++){
    $$(".item")[i].observe("click", detailPopup);
}
```

so if I click any of the elements that are of "item" class, it'll run "detailPopup" function. But I want to pass a parameter to that function. More specifically, I want "this"() to be passed.

How do I do that??

I think I made my question as specific as possible, but in case I didn't, let me know, and I'll clarify my question.

THANKS!

Comment: You want to pass the current `this`, as in what the context was when this `for` loop ran?....or the clicked element itself?  `this` should already refer to what you want in that case, just use the `this` keyword inside your `detailPopup` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't explicitly tried this myself I believe you should be able to [burn in](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/curry/) your parameters.

```
$$('.item').invoke('observe', 'click', detailPopup.curry(this));
```

A reference to `this` will then be passed before all other parameters. Your function might look something like the following...

```
function detailPopup(parent, event)
{
    ...
```

The original meaning of `this` is preserved for the handler's scope, that of the triggered element. Also I used `invoke` to avoid all that messing around with index values and anonymous functions and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind `this` to the function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $$(".item").length; i++){
    $$(".item")[i].observe("click", detailPopup.bind(this));
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/dhGuv/)

Comment: This is clever. `detailPopup`'s value of `this` will then be it's caller, instead of the element that triggered it as with normal events.

Comment: @clockworkgeek: Precisely, JavaScript frameworks are able to do this via the Function.apply() and Function.call() methods. Those two functions are pretty awesome. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create an anonymous function. In place of `detailPopup`, you should put something like: `function() { detailPopup(that); }`

What is `that`? Because the value of `this` isn't transferred to nested functions, you need to assign it to a variable before you can use it. Example: `var that = this;`

```
var that = this;

for(var i = 0; i < $$(".item").length; i++){
   $$(".item")[i].observe("click", function() { detailPopup(that); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $$(".item").length; i++){
    (function(t){
        $$(".item")[i].observe("click", function { detailPopup(t); });
    })(this);
}
```

the `(function(t){ ... })(this);` is a closure which ensures that `this` is the correct *this* otherwise you will get scoping issues. This is important in a few situations, for loops being one of them. If you didnt have a for loop you could have done this:

```
$$(".item")[i].observe("click", function { detailPopup(someParameter); });
```

Comment: What is the `(function...)(parameter)` form called?

Comment: its an anonymous self-executing function. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186024/how-do-you-explain-this-structure-in-javascript the first answer is correct.