# jQuery question: what does it really mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($, window, undefined){
  ... jquery code... 
})(jQuery, window);
```

What does it really mean? Does it also mean `$(document).ready()`? Or just two different things?

Comment: repeat question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined

Comment: No, it is not the same. This is a normal JavaScript function and apart from having jQuery inside of it, is not related to jQuery. I'm sure you are missing `())` at the end.

Comment: can you give more context ? as such it does not mean anything to me. at least one ')' is missing but still without context i cannot help you.

Comment: @Felix They're actually missing `)();`

Comment: @tylermwashburn: It doesn't matter, but JSLint favors `(function(){}());`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are already two answers but this is my guess on the missing end of the code:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
  // ... jquery code... 
})(jQuery, window);
```

Note: **three** parameters are expected but **two** are supplied.

What it basically does is:

1. gives a private scope inside curly braces, so any `var` declared inside is not visible outside
2. makes a private `$` shortcut to `jQuery` without relying on this shortcut being set globally (eg. `jQuery.noconflict()` might have been called and this would still work)
3. makes a lexical window variable that would mean faster lookups for global variables
4. makes sure that `undefined` is indeed undefined in the scope between curly braces, even if someone has written something like `undefined = "now it's defined";` in the global scope, because `undefined` can actually be redefined (this is a mistake of the language).

This pattern is known as immediately invoked function, or immediate function for short, or self-invoking anonymous function, or some other names. The basic idea is that:

```
(function (x, y) {
    // ...
})(1, 2);
```

or:

```
(function (x, y) {
    // ...
}(1, 2));
```

means the same as:

```
function myFunction (x, y) {
    // ...
}
myFunction(1, 2);
```

but without the need to give any name to your function and pollute the namespace.

Going back to your question, this doesn't mean `$(document).ready()` or anything like that, but it means that you can use `$(document).ready()` **inside** instead of `jQuery(document).ready()` even if the `$` shortcut is not available outside.

This example may actually explain it better, even if it isn't used anywhere:

```
(function (JQ, window, undefined) {

    JQ(document).ready(function () {
        // this is run when document is ready
    });

})(jQuery, window);
```

Now instead of `$` you can call jQuery as `JQ` and use `JQ(document).ready()` instead of `$(document).ready()` – it may not seem very useful but it shows what happens when you have a code like that.

As a side note I might add that thanks to this pattern you don't actually need variable declarations in the language but only function arguments. Instead of:

```
var x = 10;
alert(x * x * x);
```

you could use:

```
(function (x) {
    alert(x * x * x);
})(10);
```

and indeed a function like this:

```
function square (x) {
    // some code ...
    var result = x * x;
    return result;
}
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
function square (x, result) {
    // some code ...
    result = x * x;
    return result;
}
```

because of the hoisting mechanism in JavaScript that would make the `result` variable available (but undefined) even before the declaration and assignment in both cases (in the `// some code ...` part). This is often a source of confusion but is actually quite interesting and extremely powerful.

See also my other recently updated [answer to the question:
Help understanding JavaScript global abatement techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318921/help-understanding-javascript-global-abatement-techniques/5318958#5318958) for more info on this subject.

Comment: @Russ Cam: There are many names for it, no one of them is standard unfortunately, but I like self-invoking anonymous function so I'll add it in the answer for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: One question I continue to have on this pattern is why function arguments are used instead of a variable definition (except for the undefined). Instead why not have: 
`(function (undefined) {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var window = window;
  // ... jquery code...
})();` 
It seems more readable since the definition is next to the declaration (rather than at the end). And it also seems to meet your points 1-3. Since folks don't do this I'm sure I'm missing some subtle difference.

Comment: @studgeek I don't think you're missing any subtle difference and I don't think there is any difference at all - certainly not any difference that would be at all relevant in code like this. The only reason I believe people are using the `(function(x){...}(y))` style instead of `(function(){var x=y; ...}())` is that it looks cool and reminds some tricks from lambda calculus and combinatory logic, but I agree with you that just using `var` with assignment is more readable especially in big blocks of code where you don't immediately see what is actually assigned to the variables in question.

Answer (score 3):

```
(function($, window, undefined){
  ... jquery code... 
})();
```

is different than

```
$(document).ready()
```

Paul Irish has a good video on [10 Things I Learned from the jQuery Source](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) at 1:30 in he talks about the jquery source's self executing anonymous function and what the arguments mean

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the code actually looks like this:

```
(function($, window, undefined){
  ... jquery code... 
})(jQuery, window);
```

**Note the parenthesis at the end.**

If this is the case, what's going on here is a [**self-executing anonymous function.**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186024/497356) The point of doing this is that any local variables or functions defined inside of that anonymous function will not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: You should not pass the *undefined* argument, because it should be `undefined`. =)

Comment: @Jonathan: Unfortunately, code can redefine what `undefined` means. See @rsp for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Yep, I know, but passing undefined as an argument -> `...(jQuery, window, undefined);`, you're passing the variable from the current scope, which may have been modified.

Comment: @Jonathan: You're right; I should have omitted the last argument.

Comment: Aren't to calling parentheses supposed to be inside the enclosing parentheses? Like `(function(){}())` not `(function(){})()`

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions

Answer (score 1):

Like that it doesn't mean much at all (in addition a closing `)` is missing). What you are probably looking at is something *similar* to this:

```
(function($, window){
    // code
} )($, window);
```

This puts the code inside a new scope, so you can for example define variables without messing with the outside scope.

It also allows that you pass different things to the function, without having to change the code. For example if you use different JavaScript frameworks, and `$` is not bound to jQuery, you can pass the alternative variable for jQuery instead, while you are still using the `$` to refer to jQuery *internally*. Similar to that you could also pass a different window instance (for example from a popup).

Answer (score 0):

@rsp has a great answer for this specific question.

For general background on this pattern also see http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.