# Passed in undefined argument in jQuery core source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I noticed that in the jQuery core, one of the two arguments passed in is undefined.

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

    // Use the correct document accordingly with window argument (sandbox)
    var document = window.document;
    var jQuery = (function() {
        // ...defintion of the rest of the core...
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);
```

Can anyone explain why the second argument is *undefined*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because undefined can be overwritten and this way it is guaranteed to be undefined... My opinion.

Comment: Because Resig wanted to see how many people he could get to ask about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery question: what does it really mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305634/jquery-question-what-does-it-really-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Undefined is a type but is also a global variable.

You can have a module that overwrites the value of undefined by doing `undefined = whatever`.

jQuery uses a immediate function to scope window and undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: I marked rsp's as the answer, but this is also a good answer. Thanks masylum.

Answer (score 2):

Since someone could overwrite undefined like this

```
undefined = true;
```

Code of your immediate function will pass it as it should be (stay undefined). I think it's mentioned in [10 Things I Learned from the jQuery Source](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/).