# What is the point of doing window.undefined = window.undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at the past versions of jQuery's code, and it seems that in every version [they have this line of code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.js) somewhere inside:

```
window.undefined = window.undefined;
```

I am not able to see why is this important and more importantly, what does this do. This seems like assigning `undefined` to `undefined` which makes no sense to me.

However this seems important and I am curious about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passed in undefined argument in jQuery core source code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5395329/901048)

Comment: @Blazemonger no, I don't think so.

Comment: I think they are just making sure that the undefined property will exist. If it isn't, it's created

Comment: It was removed in this version: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.4.js

Comment: @t0mppa, nope, it still assigns it to itself. `window.undefined` will contain exactly what it contained before the assignment (unless it does not exist in the first place).

Comment: Seems like a safety check for `undefined` that someone didn't think all the way through but, like most code, existed for a long time before it was properly refactored/removed.

Comment: The only thing it does seems to be assigning itself to itself, and this line of code was kept from the start till 1.1.4, which is quite long (1-2 years).

Comment: Who says that everything in jQuery has a logically objective reason? Maybe it is there for "historical" reasons.

Comment: Since the bug tracker doesn't go back that far, you'll likely have to either dig through https://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/list?num=250&start=2692 or ask one of the core developers of jquery during that time period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`window.undefined` did not always exist, so code like `if (foo === undefined)` would throw a ReferenceError in older browsers, because `undefined` is not defined (i.e. it's not declared). This code just makes sure that `undefined` is defined (as undefined).

It is sort of unnecessary, though, because there are so many ways to get the value `undefined` without the eponymous global property. For example you could write `if (foo === void 0)` or even something like `if (foo === [][0])`.

[Later versions](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.4.js) seem to assume that `window.undefined` exists in all browsers supported. The [most recent versions](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js) use a pattern like this:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    ...
})( window );
```

Notice that no value is passed in for `undefined`, so it's guaranteed to be declared as a local variable, and have a value of `undefined`.

Comment: The global `undefined` variable was specified back in EcmaScript 3 (§15.1.1.3). Did browsers just not implement this, or have there been earlier versions that did not specify this? Which older browsers exactly do not have a global `undefined` variable?

Comment: @Bergi IIRC it was an old IE thing. I'm trying to find some evidence of this now, but having trouble digging up info on those old browsers. I do remember running into this years ago, though.

Comment: @Bergi I just checked version 2 and it doesn't seem to be specified there. IE was pretty far behind the curve in fully adopting ES3, so I suspect it was them.

Comment: Citation required. What browsers do you speak of?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum a bit of googling indicates that `undefined` didn't exist in IE 5, which makes sense given that IE5 launched 9 months before ES3 was published, and ES2 didn't specify a global `undefined` property. Since MS didn't really do much to get IE updates in front of users back then, people could have IE5 sitting on machines for years, and the oldest jQ versions probably wanted to support those users.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I remember visiting a school's computer lab in 2003 or so and half of the computers had IE6, maybe a third had IE5.5, and the rest still had IE5. These machines didn't show any sign that they needed to be updated, the students who used them didn't have the administrative privileges to do it, and the administration didn't know any better.

Answer (score 1):

Using this, jQuery defines a global variable with the real `undefined` value. having a global variable like `myvar` means you have this variable in your `window` scope (like `window.mywar`), if you run this code in the window scope:

```
var myvar = "whatever";
```

javascript defines your variable as if you have run this:

```
window.myvar = "whatever";
```

Let's assume we don't have a global variable like `myundefined` which means `window.myundefined` does not exist and `window.myundefined` has no value, it means `window.myundefined` is really `undefined`, then you can create a global variable named `undefined` in your window scope like this:

```
window.undefined = window.myundefined
```

and this line has the exact same result as the jQuery code that you have mentioned above. In other words jQuery could have done the same with this code:

```
window.undefined = window.myundefined
```

or

```
window.undefined = window.whatever_you_want_with_no_value
```

these both define a global variable with no value.